# Azure - Cloud Services - web service keeps recycling on multi core not on single core

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Our application backend is an azure cloud service (classic) - that consists of 1 web service app, and 3 worker roles.

All these 4 were running on single core VM for the last year and everything was working.

We have recently decided to deploy on a dual core VM (all 4 VMs) and started having problem.

It seems that the WebService recycles all the time.

But, not directly on startup, it might run for 3 or 4 minutes and then reboot.

What is surprising is that redeploying on one core VM again, is working without any issue.

Comment: If you've enabled diagnostics, please take a look at Event Logs and Infrastructure logs. Hopefully you should find some info there.

Comment: Seems like something specific to your app that doesn't work well in multi-core environment. But you've shown nothing about your app. As written, there's really no way to help, since web & worker roles support multi-core instances. Please edit your question with more details, before this question gets closed as "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad."

Comment: Thank you @GauravMantri - I will go through enabling diagnostics and  event logger and see what I can gather.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - Indeed we are looking at our application code to see what might be the issue. As soon as I have narrowed down to anything from this application - i can post something relevant - that would help me. Right now I am not even sure what to post. thanks.